# Cannot assign user roles in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, role

I was unable to login to wp-admin "You don't have sufficient privileges" so I added this code to my themes functions.php

```
/*
* Add your own functions here. You can also copy some of the theme functions into this file. 
* Wordpress will use those functions instead of the original functions then.
*/
function codelight_all_permissions( $allcaps, $cap, $args ) {
    $allcaps[$cap[0]] = true;
    return $allcaps;
}
add_filter( 'user_has_cap', 'codelight_all_permissions', 0, 3 );
```

Then I was able to get in as site admin, I went to users and noticed there are no  roles assigned.  In the database I have level 10 and a:1:{s:13:"administrator";s:1:"1";} assigned.

If I create a new user I cannot choose a role for that user from the dropdown. I only get the option "No role for this site". Does anyone know how I can troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Can you turn on `WP_DEBUG` and see if you're getting any errors?

Comment: I do not see any errors at all when I set up debug to true, which is weird.

Comment: Deactivating ALL (yes all) plugins temporarily to see if this resolves the problem (plugin functions can interfere). If this works, re-activate them individually (one-by-one) to find the problematic plugin(s).

Comment: No I deactivated all plugins and checked user roles still the same.

Comment: what recent activities you or other have done in the website , which in your sense can create this type of issue. Deactivating all plugin should do the work in my sense

Comment: The site had a virus before in the wp-includes/js/jscrop folder, I created a snapshot back up prior to the virus, I wiped the whole site clean directory and all, I installed a fresh copy of wordpress, I added the snapshot plugin and restored the common files except core files, to be on the safe side I reinstalled the wordpress core file folders wp-admin and wp-includes as well as the main root .php files.